# SQL query to multiple values in the same column

Tags: sql

Table like below

| ID | YEAR | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | FALSE |
| 1 | 2021 | FALSE |
| 1 | 2022 | TRUE |
| 2 | 2020 | FALSE |
| 2 | 2021 | FALSE |
| 2 | 2022 | FALSE |
| 3 | 2020 | TRUE |
| 3 | 2021 | TRUE |
| 3 | 2022 | TRUE |

I am searching for ID which has TURE and FALSE both,
I tried: where value in (True, False)--> it gave me result, ID=1,2,3. the result should return to ID=1 only
Appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is one simple option:

```sql
SELECT YEAR
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY YEAR
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = TRUE THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = FALSE THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for your help! it works for my table